# Centreon/Nagios optional arguments in commands

Tags: nagios

Is there a way to put optional arguments in **centreon/nagios**

A simple example. In Centreon:

```
$USER1$/check_http -H $ARG1$ -p $ARG2$ -w $ARG3$
```

Host **(-H)** and port **(-p)** arguments as ***required*** and warning argument **(-w)** set it as ***optional***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do

```
$USER1$/check_http -H $ARG1$ -p $ARG2$ $ARG3$
```

And set $ARG3$ if you need it.